# Positron mass in Dirac sea

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, dirac-equation, antimatter, second-quantization

I know that the modern correct interpretation of positrons is based on Fock's idea of regarding electrons and positrons on the same footing.

But my question is: How did Dirac justify the mass of positrons while they were merely holes in the Dirac sea? How could a *hole* be massive?